# UIWebView - How can I find it fully loaded its content? Especially on inline image content

Tags: ios, uiwebview, load, uiwebviewdelegate, contentsize

How can I know whether an UIWebView fully loads/shows its content? I opened a UIWebView that contains lots of inline images in a slow network connection. The UIWebView's delegate method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` was called even before it actually shows all inline images.

So, the content size of my web view varies. I want to show some other view on the bottom of UIWebview. Due to this, that another view overlaps with UIWebView.

Is there a way to find whether all inline images are visible in an UIWebview? So that I can start adding other views with reference to UIWebView's actual content size.

Note: I want to add "other" views in UIWebview's scrollview

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't solve it. Did you find some way to solve it?